# How to zoom camera in android programmatically and using android.hardware.camera2?

Tags: android, android-camera

Following is my code,

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
  int zoom = parameters.getMaxZoom();
  parameters.setZoom(10);
  camera.setParameters(parameters);
```